# Why I have pte not present pages when swap is off

Tags: linux-kernel

I go throught vm_area_struct areas of the task and try to get corresponding struct page * (pages), but some pages is not present in RAM: pte_present(*pte) returns 0. I can't understand this behaviour because I have no swap area, so I suppose that all userspace virtual space maps into presented pages in RAM. Could anybody explain me this?

```
static struct page * get_page(unsigned long addr)
{
    pgd_t *pgd;
    pte_t *pte;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    struct page *pg;
    struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
    if (pgd_none_or_clear_bad(pgd)) {
            goto err;
    }

    pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
    if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud)) {
            goto err;
    }

    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
    if (pmd_none(*pmd) || pmd_bad(*pmd)) {
            goto err;
    }

    pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
    if (!pte) {
            goto err;
    }

    if (!pte_present(*pte)) {
            PR("pte is not present\n");
            goto err;
    }

    pg = pte_page(*pte);
    if (!pg) {                
            pte_unmap(pte);
            goto err;
    }

    pte_unmap(pte);
```

Comment: Can you post your code with which you check?

Answer (score 3):

pte_none checks that there is no value in pte, pte_present check flag of presence.

```
#define pte_none(pte)           (!pte_val(pte))
#define pte_present(pte)        (pte_isset((pte), L_PTE_PRESENT))
```

so the condition for swapped out pages would be `!pte_present && !pte_none`

And in your case you interpret all empty ptes as swapped out...

Answer (score 0):

It may be a minor page fault where the memory region is reserved, but not allocated with data yet.